# Python unexpected copies of strings running in interpreter or Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, string, string-literals, names

I thought I understood Python names and immutable objects such as strings until I got this unexpected behaviour in a Jupyter notebook.  Then I noticed the same code has different result when you run at as a Python script file (.py) from the command line.

1. Executing as `.py` script (using Python 2.7.12)

Script file:

```
a, b = 'my text', 'my text'

print id(a), id(b), a is b

c = 'my text'
d = 'my text'

print id(c), id(d), c is d
```

Output

```
4300053168 4300053168 True
4300053168 4300053168 True
```

As I expected - Python does not make copies of strings.  All names point to the same object.

2. Interpreting in interactive iPython (version 2.7.12)

If I enter the exact same code above into an iPython interactive shell or a Jupyter notebook cell I get output like this

```
4361310096 4361310096 True
4361509168 4361509648 False
```

In the second case, Python has created two new objects to represent `'my text'`.

The reason for this post is that I am developing code in the notebook that uses identity tests such as `a is 'my text'` (rather than `a == 'my text'`).  I thought this would be a very efficient, yet readable way to achieve what I want to achieve.  Obviously, for this to work consistently, I need to ensure that there are no duplicates of each string literal.

Comment: But basically, `a, b = 'my text', 'my text'` is not guaranteed to create a single `'my text'` string object, and it depends on rather cryptic string interning implementation details. You should *never* use `is` to check for string equality.

Comment: And actually, by the normal python behavior you wouldn't expect this to make two identical objects, so `a, b = (1,2), (1,2)` and check `a is b` is `False`, and the fact that it is `True` sometimes with strings is what should be surprising. Essentially, in some cases the CPython interpreter can optimize and intern string *literals*, but this is an implementation detail that should not be relied upon. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504848/5014455) answer in the dupe target.

Comment: My understanding is this is due to interned strings. The explanation I found helpful was the second response a linked question. The direct link is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504848/1772166. Additionally, the `intern` function may be of assistance, per this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504870/1772166

Comment: Thanks everyone.  That's a shame as the identity check is so much faster than a string comparison (20 times in the quick test I did).  Can you at least rely on identical string literals being the same object in a script file and thus use identity checking or is it better to avoid identify checks completely?